# push в приложении gitkraken

Tags: git, git-push

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]что именно вводить когда нажимаешь push в gitkraken?

Comment: А то в инете крайне моло информации

Comment: Для скриншотов используйте Shift + PrintScreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой, решить её в лоб не получилось, поэтому я воспользовался обходным путем. Если еще актуально для Вас, то вот решение данной проблемы:

Для того чтобы опция "Push" заработала, Вам нужен репозиторий на удалённом сервере (например на GitHub). Репозиторий - это папка в котором будет храниться Ваш проект. Репозиториев на сервере может быть много (под каждый проект своя папка).
    Cоздайте папку под Ваш проект на GitHub.com (иначе Gitkraken не понимает куда выгружать все изменения).
    Сразу после создания репозитория на GitHub (например) Вы увидете следующее сообщение внутри Вашего репозитория:
    **…or create a new repository on the command line**

```
echo "# ProgrammingInLinuxBook" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/имяПользователя/названиеРепозитория.git
git push -u origin master
```

(Эти команды мы будем использовать.)

- Далее, зайдите в папку Вашего проекта на компьютере (не на GitHub).
- Я работаю с Linux и у меня установлен Git. В любом случае Вам нужно установить Git.
- Если у Вас Linux: зайдите в папку проекта и откройте Терминал (правой кнопкой мыши на пустом месте --> Open in Terminal)
- Если у вас Windows: откройте терминал (или что там устанавливается с Git) и перейдите в папку проекта командами CD...
- Далее введите в Терминале команду:`echo "# НазваниеПапкиВашегоПроекта" >> README.md`
- Название папки проекта должно быть таким же, как название репозитория на GitHub.
- Далее введите в Терминале команду: `git init`
- Далее введите в Терминале команду: `git add README.md`
- Далее введите в Терминале команду: `git commit -m "first commit"`
- Далее введите в Терминале команду: `git remote add origin https://github.com/имяПользователя/названиеРепозитория.git`
- Далее введите в Терминале команду: `git push -u origin master`
- Всё. Теперь откройте GitKraken, там слева есть иконка ввиде облака, там появится Ваш удалённый репозиторий. Попробуйте теперь нажать кнопку Push.

Answer (score 1):

### Upstream branch <sub>*(там же написано)*</sub>

**Локальное зеркало ветки на сервере**, за которой будет следить (track) указанная **локальная ветка**.

Если это единственный удалённый (remote) репозиторий, с которым вы планируете работать из этого локального, то есть смысл держать названия их веток одинаковыми.

**Посему, `origin/master` сгодится**.

---

## Но есть проблема куда смешнее: `Remotes 0/0`

У вас не указан ни один удалённый репозиторий. `origin` не существует. Добавьте его.

Comment: Смотри я ввожу master и кнопка submit становиться неактивной

Comment: она активна только если я еще ничего не ввел

Comment: Хм. А что на счёт `origin/master`?

Comment: так же ничего..Я бы не писал если бы не попробовал хоть какие-то елементырные варианты

Comment: `попробовал хоть какие-то елементырные варианты` - shotgun-version-control.

Answer (score 1):

> что именно вводить когда нажимаешь push в gitkraken

Для push необходима

- локальная ветка, из которой будет производиться push
- ветка удалённого репозитория, в которую будет производиться этот push
- и сам удалённый репозиторий нужен, конечно

У вас в левой панели: REMOTE 0/0.

Что это означает:

- либо не настроен удалённый репозиторий, куда можно было бы пушить
- либо настроен, но с него ни разу не забирались данные (fetch).

Решение: настройте удалённый репозиторий и обновите данные с него. А ещё убедитесь, что вы не путаете push и commit.

Comment: Я добавил remote и что-то все равно осталось все так само

Comment: @darkwoolf а изменения вы после этого подтянули с сервера? `git fetch` в консоли или какая-нибудь похожая кнопочка.

Comment: странный вопрос но можешь обяснить в скайпе или типо того...Просто такая фигня, а нормально из-за этого работать не могу

Comment: буду сверх благодарен

Comment: @darkwoolf Я бы рекомендовал попробовать в командной строке, без клиента. Он вносит ненужную сложность. Рискнёте?

Comment: Типо сделать пуш через терминал?